# How to update html without reloading the page every time I get a new database entry

Tags: node.js, ajax, reactjs, mongodb, ejs

I am setting up a node.js server which constantly checks a mongo database for new entries. If a new entry comes the html site should get updated without a reload and with the data from the database.

I can already receive the data every time a new entry is made, but I can't update the site.
I looked up some possible tools like ajax or react.js but I just don't find the perfect solution (or even a solution) of how this could work.

Connection to Mongodb and receiving the data

```js
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://192.168.128.128:27017/familientag', function(err, client) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('An error occurred connecting to MongoDB: ', err);
  } else {
    const db = client.db("familientag")
    const collection = db.collection('data');
    console.log("Connected successfully to server");

    const changeStream = collection.watch();
    changeStream.on('change', next => {
      console.log(next.fullDocument['name']);
      // Here I receive the data "_id" and "name"
    });
  }
});
```

My index.ejs

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Dies ist ein Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="target">
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/test',
                success: function(data) {
                    var html = data;
                    $('#target').html(html);
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

call index

```js
app.get('/index', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});
```

I expect to see the name on the index site everytime a new dataset has been read from the db without reloading the window.

Comment: I propose you in your database to add a coulumn, and call it something like `updateID`, than for each update u make in the webside, increment the value so you can check with ajax if updateID is same as last ID you allready updated!

Comment: That's not really the problem. I get the data to the node.js app but I cant get it to the frontend.

Comment: I suggest taking a look into websockets, for continuous streaming of data to the client. Should be pretty straight forward to integrate in your nodejs server.

Comment: You should use a websocket communication or a long polling system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an open socket should help you out. You can either pass the new data into the socket body, or simply trigger the UI to request the data from an api.

I'd recommend taking a look at socket.io: https://socket.io/ to get going very quickly. It's a flexible socket framework for node with brilliant docs.

Pusher is a great option if you want to manage less of the socket state yourself. Comes with its own UI. https://pusher.com/

Comment: Worked with socket.io. But watch out at the example if you install socket.io it downloaded version 2.2. It only worked with version 1.7.3.

Comment: I couldn't even connect to the socket even with the github example. As I saw that the example used socket.io version 1.7.3 and I used 2.2.0 I changed to 1.7.3 and it work all fine. The "Get started" said to use `npm install --save socket.io` which downloaded version 2.2.0.